# doctrine2 schema update drop foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I update my schema (php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
), generated tables don't have foreign key constraint.
In phpmyadmin I can insert data manually in these tables without put value for foreign keys (ManyToOne variable in Doctrine ORM Entity).

So I ask myself is it a normal behavior or am I missing something while creating entities.

Thank's a lot (and sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this with your annotations and map on both entities:

Please see:

[How can I use 'foreign key' on doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970191/how-can-i-use-foreign-key-on-doctrine)

and

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetomany

for examples.